# POST request made to Plug router with HTTPoison fails

Tags: elixir, cowboy, plug

I'm trying to make a POST request to a Plug router using HTTPoison. My GET requests are successful, it is only the POST that is failing. I'm not sure if the problem is Plug or HTTPoison:

```
# server.ex

defmodule MyServer do
  use Application
  use Plug.Router

  import Plug.Conn, only: [put_resp_header: 3, send_resp: 3]

  alias Plug.Adapters.Cowboy

  plug(:match)

  plug(Plug.Parsers,
    parsers: [:json],
    pass: ["*/*", "application/json", "text/plain"],
    json_decoder: Poison
  )

  plug(:dispatch)

  post "/myserver/url" do
    conn
    |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(%{}))
  end

  def start(_type, _args) do
    port = Application.get_env(:server, :cowboy_port, 8030)
    IO.puts("Started server on http://localhost:#{port}/")

    children = [
      Cowboy.child_spec(:http, __MODULE__, [], port: port)
    ]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

And the client:

```
# client.ex

host = "http://localhost:8030"

host
|> Path.join("/myserver/url")
|> HTTPoison.post!(Poison.encode!(%{}))
|> IO.inspect()
```

The response I get is a 500. I'm not sure why, since the route in the router is configured to accept POSTs. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

People have asked for the stack trace. There isn't one. But this is the 500 response:

```
..%HTTPoison.Response{
  body: "",
  headers: [
    {"server", "Cowboy"},
    {"date", "Fri, 02 Nov 2018 20:57:01 GMT"},
    {"content-length", "0"}
  ],
  request_url: "http://localhost:8030/myserver/url"
  status_code: 500
}
```

Comment: Post the full error stack trace of your Router.

Comment: That's not possible, there has to be a stack trace or the code you've provided is incomplete. [See this](https://github.com/sheharyarn/ex_gun/blob/master/lib/ex_gun/web/router.ex) on how to write a plug router.

Comment: Try using [`Plug.Debugger`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Debugger.html) to get a useful error message.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with this line:

```
send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(stuff))
```

You haven't defined a variable named `stuff`, so it throws an exception which returns a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: `stuff` was a place holder

Comment: You should have made that clear in your question. Please post the full error stack trace of your Router.